# Как добавить или удалить атрибут jsx элемента в react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, атрибуты

Насколько я понимаю, в react не работаю такие методы как setAttribute, getAttribute и т.д. Тогда каким образом мне убрать например, такой атрибут, как readonly?
Пытался через через createRef и removeAttribute, не получилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Касательно `readonly` можно сделать через `state`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
 
  const [isReadonly, setIsReadonly] = useState(true);
  return (
      <div>
          <input type="text" readOnly={isReadonly}/>
          <button onClick={()=> setIsReadonly(prevState => !prevState)}/>
      </div>
  );
}
```